# AWS EMR: Zeppelin taking numpy version from python 2.7 instead of higher version

Tags: numpy, pip, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I have python 2.7(default) and python 3.6 on my EMR (5.26.0) cluster and below is my bootstrap script. I am installing numpy version `1.18.5` and I can see that it is getting installed in the bootstrap logs. However in the python3 packages I see it is picking the numpy `1.14.5` which comes from Python 2.7. If you see the below screenshot I can see version `1.18.5` dist. files there in the python packages directory but the binary is for but the actual numpy version has files for `1.14.5`.

[image]

[image]

I am using zeppelin notebook and changed my interpreters python and pyspark properties to use python 3 by setting below variables but

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON = '/usr/bin/python3'
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = '/usr/bin/python3'

# In zeppelin interpretor
zeppelin.pyspark.python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 -m pip uninstall botocore --user
python3 -m pip uninstall boto3 --user


sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

sudo python3 -m pip install botocore==1.13.38 --user

sudo python3 -m pip install h5py 
sudo python3 -m pip install keras==2.3.0 
sudo python3 -m pip install keras_applications==1.0.8 --no-deps
sudo python3 -m pip install keras_preprocessing==1.1.2 --no-deps

sudo python3 -m pip install tqdm 

sudo python3 -m pip install s3fs 
sudp python3 -m pip install ipaddress==1.0.23 
sudo python3 -m pip install netaddr==0.7.19 

sudo python3 -m pip install matplotlib

sudo python3 -m pip install pyarrow
sudo python3 -m pip install boto3
sudo python3 -m pip install torch==1.6.0
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade scipy==1.4.1
sudo python3 -m pip install torchvision
sudo python3 -m pip install pydot
sudo python3 -m pip install xlrd
sudo python3 -m pip install xlwt
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas
sudo python3 -m pip install scikit-learn
sudo python3 -m pip install scikit-multilearn 
sudo python3 -m pip install wrapt==1.12.0
sudo python3 -m pip install tensorflow==2.3.0
sudo python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
sudo python3 -m pip install numpy==1.18.5
```

Also when I do list packages I see it list `1.18.5` however numpy version command shows `1.14.5`.

How can I force Python to pick higher version of numpy?

[image]

Comment: Which mode do you use ? yarn-client or yarn-cluster ?

Comment: Cluster mode @zjffdu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working with emr-5.31.0 and below bootstrap configuration, 5.31+ defaults to Python 3 and numpy 1.16.5 even though python 2 is present in env. So I got the default higher version of numpy which solved my cross dependencies issue.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install h5py==2.10.0
sudo python3 -m pip install keras==2.3.1
sudo python3 -m pip install keras_applications==1.0.8 --no-deps
sudo python3 -m pip install keras_preprocessing==1.1.0 --no-deps

sudo python3 -m pip install tqdm==4.40.0

sudo python3 -m pip install s3fs 
sudo python3 -m pip install ipaddress==1.0.23
sudo python3 -m pip install netaddr==0.7.19 

sudo python3 -m pip install matplotlib

sudo python3 -m pip install pyarrow==0.12.1
sudo python3 -m pip install boto3
sudo python3 -m pip install torch==1.6.0
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade scipy==1.4.1
sudo python3 -m pip install torchvision
sudo python3 -m pip install pydot==1.4.1
sudo python3 -m pip install xlrd
sudo python3 -m pip install xlwt
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas==1.2.0
sudo python3 -m pip install scikit-learn
sudo python3 -m pip install scikit-multilearn 
sudo python3 -m pip install wrapt==1.12.0
sudo python3 -m pip install tensorboard==2.1.0
sudo python3 -m pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
sudo python3 -m pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
```

Comment: so , you use the numpy version of python 2 ? can share configs.json pls ? , the PYSPARK_PYTHON" is "/usr/bin/python" ?

Comment: EMR 5.31 comes with numpy 1.16 and in spark interpretor I set these properties `"PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/usr/bin/python3"`
`"PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON":"/usr/bin/python3"`

Comment: @Explorer - can you please clearly state what you did to get it working. I have exactly same issue that pyspark complains numpy 1.16.5 while when i list out packages, a higher package is there for numpy. I have set these properties in the interpretor as well but its not working.

Comment: @toing while creating your cluster add these 2 variable in your spark configuration Json.